# How to use one function within multiple files in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, routes

So i have this one function which i am defining in my `checkIfLogin.js`

```
    function authCheck (req, res, next) {
      if (req.session.loggedin) {
          next();
      } else {
          res.render('login.ejs')
     }
  }
```

I want to use this function for e.g. in my `dashboard.js`, and `clients.js` page as well. How can i export function from one page and use it in ALL pgaes in my app. I have a main `index.js` file within my root dir that hosts all the imported files, but how can i import something like this to use the function within ALL files in my project?

Comment: https://nodejs.dev/learn/expose-functionality-from-a-nodejs-file-using-exports

Answer (score 1):

Use [modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html):

Export your function in `checkIfLogin.js`:

```js
exports.authCheck = function authCheck (req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.loggedin) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.render('login.ejs')
  }
}
```

Import your function in `otherFile.js`:

```js
var authCheck = require('./checkIfLogin.js').authCheck;
```

The string in `require` is your file path.

**another approach**

if you want to call this function before or after any api route you can use middleware

[express middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)